# I unable to create android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I click for creating android new project this window open .I have been restart even though I can't do this. error image is as.[image]

and when click for check update from help menu then this error occure and pop up is that no update found what is problem ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in these three steps

**1.** goto window->Android SDK manager

[image: first]

**2.** Select Tools as in picture

[image: second]

**3.** then hit Install 2 packages at right bottom corner and let it be updated.

[image: third]

Answer (score 1):

How about updating or re-installing the ADT plug-in by following the official guide?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Answer (score 0):

So you have to update Android SDK itself with new platform versions (the dialog you're not seeing) came out after the R20 SDK.

The easiest thing to do is go to the [SDK page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download the newest version of the SDK. From there you'll be able to follow the guide you mentioned without problem.